# Enlarge UIScrollview's content size dynamically when adding views programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following situation:

- UIScrollView ("_scrollView") with one child: UIView
- UIView ("_layoutContainer") has a unknown number of childViews
- childViews of UIView are added programmatically and their constraints are set programmatically.

Code for adding childviews (and my try to resize scrollview's content size):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView* lastLabel = _topCollectionView;
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        UILabel* imageLabelView = [UILabel new];
        imageLabelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [_layoutContainer addSubview:imageLabelView];

        [_layoutContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[labelview]-(10)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"labelview":imageLabelView}]];
        [_layoutContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousLabel]-(10)-[imagelabel(40)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"previousLabel":lastLabel, @"imagelabel":imageLabelView}]];

        imageLabelView.text = @"DUMMY";
        lastLabel = imageLabelView;
    }

    [_layoutContainer setNeedsLayout];
    [_layoutContainer layoutIfNeeded];
    _scrollView.contentSize = _layoutContainer.frame.size;
    [_scrollView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

My Storyboard Constraints look like this:

[image: Constraints in Storyboard]

This code works without any constraint errors in log and it looks like expected.

My problem is:
The scrollview's content size doesn't change. I can add as many labels as I want to, but scrolling never works.
Can you please help me to dynamically enlarge my scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

If all the constraints makes a sufficient set to define an intrinsic content size in the container view, the scroll view `-contentSize` should resize accordingly, just need to call `-(void)invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` on the scroll view after you added the content.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView* lastLabel = _topCollectionView;
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        UILabel* imageLabelView = [UILabel new];
        imageLabelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [_layoutContainer addSubview:imageLabelView];

        [_layoutContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[labelview]-(10)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"labelview":imageLabelView}]];
        [_layoutContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousLabel]-(10)-[imagelabel(40)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"previousLabel":lastLabel, @"imagelabel":imageLabelView}]];

        imageLabelView.text = @"DUMMY";
        lastLabel = imageLabelView;
    }

    [_layoutContainer setNeedsLayout];
    [_layoutContainer layoutIfNeeded];
    [_scrollView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [_scrollView setNeedsLayout];
    [_scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.
If I log the `_layoutContainer` size after adding all the view, i still get `{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}` . I think the View inside the scrollView isn't updated. Will test some more..

Comment: Ok, try also that: do not call -layoutIfNeeded in the loop, after the loop say to the container view  -setNeedsLayout and then -layoutIfNeeded. You should alway mark a view as in need of layout or the layout engine will skip it. I Updated the answer

Comment: Did it (and updated the code in my question). Unfortunately it did not change anything.

Comment: Got it! I had to add a bottom view constraint for the last label (after the loop): `if (lastLabel) {
        [_layoutContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousLabel]-(10)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"previousLabel":lastLabel}]];
        
    }
` . Please edit your answer so I can accept it. Your _if all the constraints makes a sufficient set (...)_ pointed me in the right direction